# Is it possible to start a PhD without a Master degree?

Tags: phd, masters, united-kingdom, bachelor

I heard that it is possible to start a PhD without Master degree in the UK, i.e. to start a PhD after a Bachelor degree (3 years).

Is it really possible? What are the conditions?

Is there any other countries which allow this?

Comment: I think it would be quite unusual, if it does happen. A bit of context would help. For example, what subject? Is this something you are considering doing or are you just curious about it as a hypothetical question?

Comment: It will depend on the university. And the conditions surrounding. And who gives you a reference. I know of a person who got into the PhD program at Cambridge with  no undergrad degree, based on Einstein supporting him.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Moffat_(physicist)  But it's not the way to bet. :^)

Comment: Other countries - yes. Most obviously, the US, but apparently Germany also allows that https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176908/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-country-x. Also see the answer for the UK there for the reasons behind most PhD applicants actually holding MSc while only BSc is formally required.

Comment: Have you checked the entry requirements for any PhD programs before asking this question here? Sorry for issuing the close vote. At least I upvoted you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem the OP did any research before asking this question. I will vote to reopen if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A masters degree is rarely a formal requirement for entry to a PhD in any British university. However, depending on the university, the course and the year, students without master's degrees may find themselves at a competitive disadvantage when they are competing for scarce PhD places.

I went straight from my 3 year undergrad into a PhD in genetics. At that time (15 years ago), it would have been unusual to have an MSc in biology before doing a PhD. MSc were regarded as either professional training or for people who didn't do well enough at undergraduate. The situation has been changing however. Seven years ago, when I started as faculty, the of first three PhD students I supervised two had come straight from 3 year undergraduate degrees, and one had a masters degree (actaully, a 4 year undergrad with integrated masters). I think this year 7 of the 10 successful candidate for our PhD program had masters degrees.

Thats just biology, the story is different in other subjects. For example, even 15 years ago, a Masters degree was functionally necessary for a PhD in archology (even if not formally required).